# Microsoft graph create team API not working

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Please find request bellow

**PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/team**
**Content-type**: application/json
**Request Body**

```
{
"memberSettings": {
"allowCreateUpdateChannels": true
},
"messagingSettings": {
"allowUserEditMessages": true,
"allowUserDeleteMessages": true
},
"funSettings": {
"allowGiphy": true,
"giphyContentRating": "strict"
}
}
Response :
{
"error": {
"code": "BadGateway",
"message": "Failed to execute backend request.",
"innerError": {
"request-id": "d7dd5e79-c675-4310-8a72-d8f4cb92788a",
"date": "2020-05-20T05:55:15"
}
}
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Until now i created teams using the Microsoft Graph .NET API, so there may be a difference there. 
But i found out, you have send an `ODataType` with your request, even if its `null`, in your case it would be:

```
{
  "memberSettings": {
    "allowCreateUpdateChannels": true,
    "ODataType": null
  },
  "messagingSettings": {
    "allowUserEditMessages": true,
    "allowUserDeleteMessages": true,
    "ODataType": null
  },
  "funSettings": {
    "allowGiphy": true,
    "giphyContentRating": "strict",
    "ODataType": null
  },
  "ODataType": null
}
```